# Vim filereadable returns true for user script but false for plugins

Tags: vim

If I create a file `test.vim` with the below contents and run `:so %` then `filereadable` return true and foo, bar is appended to the file.

```
let lines = ["foo", "bar"]
let g:neobundle#log_filename=expand('~/.vim/plugin_install.log')
if filereadable(g:neobundle#log_filename)
  let lines = readfile(g:neobundle#log_filename) + lines
endif
call writefile(lines, g:neobundle#log_filename)
```

But if I run the exact same code from [neobundle.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim) (**code highlighted [here](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/blob/4c3ae4e6e6fa4dc0a3138ec4f15bd571ebee1a54/autoload/neobundle/installer.vim#L585-L592)**) then `filereadable` return false and the file is overwritten. Even if I `chmod 777` the file.

What could be causing this change in behavior of `filereadable` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log of neobundle is cleared before installing. (code is [here](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/blob/4c3ae4e6e6fa4dc0a3138ec4f15bd571ebee1a54/autoload/neobundle/installer.vim#L68))

Comment: Thanks! I opened a pull request to make that clearing of the log file optional https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/pull/47